# jquery append and javascript appendChild not working for html tags period

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendto

I started out trying to add meta tags in the `<head>` tags but now have found that I can't add anything to any html tags. Not `<body>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`, nothing but it works fine with div id's and classes.

Here's the html

```
    <! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="append.js"></script>
<title>appendTest</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
<p>
Hello World
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the append.js examples I've tried

```
    function loadmeta(){
var meta = "<meta name='og:title' content='some random content' />";
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(meta);
}

window.onload = function(){
loadmeta();
}




/*jquery style*/

$(document).ready(function(){
$('html').append('meta name="testing" content="some content"/>');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('meta name="testing" content="some content"/>').appendTo('html');
});
```

Now I tried the jquery functions both append and appendTo with the p#test for the div and I can append to it with both functions. However I tried with head, body, p and it doesn't work with any of them.

I'm beginning to wonder is there is some kind of security setting on my server that is stopping it because I have used append to append text and css styles and append to the body before and had no problem.

firebug gives no errors and I've tried it in FF and Chrome.

Although I don't want to feel like an idiot I'd love if someone sees some silly mistake I made.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the element correctly

```
function loadmeta(){
  var meta = document.createElement("meta");
  meta.name='og:title'; // or meta.setAttribute("name","og:title");
  meta.content='some random content';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
}
```

However I am not even sure your meta tags will be interpreted after the load of the page

Comment: Thank you, between you and paulPro I now see two ways to achieve this with javascript and they both make sense to me. Same situation with both methods as far as seeing it in the source code. It only shows when I look in firebug. This makes me wonder if even forcing an application to reparse the page after the meta tag insert will work. I'm wondering if the application will see the new tag on a reparse if I can't see it when viewing the source. Either way, you guys answered my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

None of your codes are correct:

First of all for your javascript only version appendChild expects a node, not a string of HTML.

You could do something like:

```
var meta = "<meta name='og:title' content='some random content' />";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.innerHTML = meta+head.innerHTML;
```

You jQUery methods are both missing the opening HTML tag.

Comment: Why not use createElement - what you do there will AFAIK depending on browser, change the innerHTML to what the browser sees as innerHTML

Comment: Thank you for your response. The javascript method you suggest works I think. I assumed after loading the page viewing the source I would see the new meta tag but I can only see it in firebug. As for the jquery style functions, oops I meant to put 'head', not 'html' but still, what do you mean by 'opening tags'? Everywhere I've seen examples, it was simply $('head').append('text'); to append some text to the head and I was thinking that would put it in between the head tags. Same concept for the html tags. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: I mean the less than sign in front of meta. You are appending 'meta name...' where you want to be appending '<meta name...'